# Finding and repairing broken section links on Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I want to find broken section links on Wikipedia so that I can repair them. How can I find links to non-existent sections on Wikipedia (such as `[[Google#fbffgfd]]`) and replace them with working links (such as `[[Google#History]]`)? Is there a specific category for broken section links such as these, or are tools available for finding them?

Comment: To clarify, I want to find a list of all the currently broken section links on Wikipedia.

Comment: A related question: is it possible to obtain a list of all the links to sections on Wikipedia, so that they can be replaced with links to redirect pages?

Comment: I want to do this because links to a section become "broken" when the name of the section is changed.

Comment: Here's a page with a slightly outdated list of broken section links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_reports/Broken_section_anchors

Comment: It would also be useful if I could find a "what links here" feature for individual sections.

Comment: Also, is it possible to make one section link redirect to another section link (so that [[Google#History of Google]] would redirect to [[Google#History]])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a comment [here in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk%3aDatabase_reports) to ask that the report be updated.

Comment: Which report are you referring to?

Comment: It's also possible to fix broken section links by adding an anchor to a section. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37486/20087

Answer (score -2):

You can search for

> site:wikipedia.org [keyword] + "dead link"

on Google.